# Redirect to internal URL after login - Drupal 8

Tags: drupal, drupal-8, drupal-modules

On my D8 site I want to redirect all users to an internal URL after they login. below is my snippet:

```
function mymodule_user_login($account) {
    $url = Url::fromUri('internal:/dashboard-overview');
    $response = new RedirectResponse($url->toString());
    $response->send();
}
```

This snippet redirects to "Access denied" error page even for administrators. There is no permission set to visit this URL. Still the page is not loading even for admins. Any help ?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried this module? https://www.drupal.org/project/redirect_after_login
i think it will do the task you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Drupal 8 and 9
You need to alter the login form and add a submit handler which will take care of the redirection. You cannot use $form_state->setRedirectUrl() directly in the form alter, since it will be overwritten by UserForm::submitForm().

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form_FORM_ID_alter().
 */
function mymodule_form_user_login_form_alter(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  $form['#submit'][] = 'mymodule_user_login_submit';
}

/**
 * Form submission handler for user_login_form().
 *
 * Redirects the user to the dashboard after logging in.
 */
function mymodule_user_login_submit(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  $url = Url::fromRoute('mymodule.dashboard');

  // Check if a destination was set, probably on an exception controller.
  // @see \Drupal\user\Form\UserLoginForm::submitForm()
  $request = \Drupal::service('request_stack')->getCurrentRequest();
  if (!$request->request->has('destination')) {
    $form_state->setRedirectUrl($url);
  }
  else {
    $request->query->set('destination', $request->request->get('destination'));
  }
}
```